# GLSL blank screen

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am getting a blank window (white) for my GLSL shader program. My program compiles fine with a warning level of 4. The only error I am getting is from the shaders are:

Both shaders (vertex and fragment) getting this error:

WARNING: 0:? : ' : Version number deprecated in OGL 3.0 forward compatible context driver

frgment shader getting this error:

ERROR 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version is mandatory and should be set before any other token

I am running opengl 4.0 using GLEW and have intel HD 4000 graphic card.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400

layout (std140) uniform Matrices {
    mat4 pvm;
} ;

in vec4 position;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pvm * position ;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputF;

void main()
{
    outputF = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

file reading method:

```
static char* textFileRead(const char *fileName) {
    char* text;

    if (fileName != NULL) {
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rt");

        if (file != NULL) {
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
            int count = ftell(file);
            rewind(file);

            if (count > 0) {
                text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
                count = fread(text, sizeof(char), count, file);
                text[count] = '\0';
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

I have tried different shaders, removing version number and changing version number.

Comment: Have you tried setting both versions to 400?

Comment: Yeah I always have them as the same version when running the program.  I think when I copy and pasted the code I forgot to changed one back to 400.

Comment: When you tried using different shaders, did you get the same error?

Comment: yeah I get the same problem with different vertex and fragment shaders.

Comment: If you print out the text returned from textFileRead(), do you get the text you would expect?

Comment: I do get what is in the textfile when I print the textfile. I have solved the last error dealing with mandatory version number after I commented out some duplicated code. I used glGetError and it prints out "invalid enumerant".